# How to draw contour of obstructed/overlapping object?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, contour

I'm trying to get OpenCV to recognize, that the red area is one contour rather than segmenting it into two separate contours. I have tried messing with hierarchies, but to no success. Any ideas?

The image and the code are provided below.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
black = (0,0,0)
# All of these are in hsv format
lb=np.array([0,181,0])
ub=np.array([6,255,255])
# Load img
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
img=cv2.resize(img,(400,400))

kernelOpen=np.ones((5,5))
kernelClose=np.ones((20,20))
#convert BGR to HSV
imgHSV= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# create the Mask
mask = cv2.inRange(imgHSV, lb, ub)
maskso=cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
masksc=cv2.morphologyEx(maskso,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)
conts,hiers=cv2.findContours(masksc.copy(),cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
# Create convex hull
hull = []
for i in range(len(conts)):
    # creating convex hull object for each contour
    hull.append(cv2.convexHull(conts[i], False))
# Draw contour
cv2.drawContours(img,hull,-1,black,2)

cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey(5000)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: Without contours drawn]

[image: With contours drawn]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replacing this code fragment

```py
# Create convex hull
hull = []
for i in range(len(conts)):
    # creating convex hull object for each contour
    hull.append(cv2.convexHull(conts[i], False))
# Draw contour
cv2.drawContours(img,hull,-1,black,2)
```

with

```py
# Create convex hull
hull = np.zeros((0, 1, 2), np.int32)
for i in range(len(conts)):
    hull = np.concatenate((hull, conts[i]), axis=0)
hull = cv2.convexHull(hull, False)
# Draw contour
cv2.drawContours(img,[hull],-1,black,2)
```

I get the following output, which I assume is what you want:

[image: Output]

Instead of collecting the single convex hulls of each contour, I collect all contours, and then get the convex hull of all contour points.

Hope that helps!

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:    Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:      3.8.1
NumPy:       1.18.1
OpenCV:      4.2.0
----------------------------------------
```